# how to rotate log file with date in filename (ex: debug.log.2019-04-24) in erlang lager

Tags: erlang, lager

I used the lagger lager_file_backend setting:

```
{lager_file_backend, 
[{file, "debug.log"}, {level, debug},
    {size, 10485760}, {date, "$D0"}, {count, 30},
    {formatter_config,
        [date, " ", time, " ", pid, " ", module, ":", line, " [", severity, "] ", message, "\n"]}]}
```

erlang lager logfile is rotated with count and size, that result in

```
debug.log
debug.log.0
debug.log.1
```

how to rotate log file with date in filename?

```
debug.log
debug.log.2019-04-24
debug.log.2019-04-23
```

Comment: Could you please provide your `app.config` of lager? I think the description in [here] (https://www.diycode.cc/projects/basho/lager) can help you.

Comment: I had read the document "Internal log rotation" but don't know how to support datetime log filename.

Answer (score 2):

[leo_logger_rotator.erl](https://github.com/leo-project/leo_logger/blob/3e592ad78d0dbdf68aa5541ac08b2d9e449698c2/src/leo_logger_rotator.erl) provides a hint for the solution.

We can modify lager_rotator_default.erl to our lager_rotator.erl that is  "Custom Log Rotation" feature in lager.

```
-module(lager_rotator).

-include_lib("kernel/include/file.hrl").

-behaviour(lager_rotator_behaviour).

-export([
  create_logfile/2, open_logfile/2, ensure_logfile/4, rotate_logfile/2
]).

create_logfile(Name, Buffer) ->
  {{Y, M, D}, {H, _, _}} = calendar:now_to_local_time(os:timestamp()),
  DateHour =  {Y, M, D, H},
  FileName = filename(Name, DateHour, 1),
  file:delete(Name),
  file:make_symlink(filename:absname(FileName), Name),
  open_logfile(Name, Buffer).

open_logfile(Name, Buffer) ->
  case filelib:ensure_dir(Name) of
    ok ->
      Options = [append, raw] ++
        case  Buffer of
          {Size, Interval} when is_integer(Interval), Interval >= 0, is_integer(Size), Size >= 0 ->
            [{delayed_write, Size, Interval}];
          _ -> []
        end,
      case file:open(Name, Options) of
        {ok, FD} ->
          case file:read_file_info(Name) of
            {ok, FInfo} ->
              Inode = FInfo#file_info.inode,
              {ok, {FD, Inode, FInfo#file_info.size}};
            X -> X
          end;
        Y -> Y
      end;
    Z -> Z
  end.


ensure_logfile(Name, FD, Inode, Buffer) ->
  case file:read_link(Name) of
    {ok, _} ->
      lager_ensure_logfile(Name, FD, Inode, Buffer);
    _ ->
      create_logfile(Name, Buffer)
  end.


lager_ensure_logfile(Name, undefined, _Inode, Buffer) ->
  open_logfile(Name, Buffer);
lager_ensure_logfile(Name, FD, Inode, Buffer) ->
  case file:read_file_info(Name) of
    {ok, FInfo} ->
      Inode2 = FInfo#file_info.inode,
      case Inode == Inode2 of
        true ->
          {ok, {FD, Inode, FInfo#file_info.size}};
        false ->
          %% delayed write can cause file:close not to do a close
          _ = file:close(FD),
          _ = file:close(FD),
          case open_logfile(Name, Buffer) of
            {ok, {FD2, Inode3, Size}} ->
              %% inode changed, file was probably moved and
              %% recreated
              {ok, {FD2, Inode3, Size}};
            Error ->
              Error
          end
      end;
    _ ->
      %% delayed write can cause file:close not to do a close
      _ = file:close(FD),
      _ = file:close(FD),
      case open_logfile(Name, Buffer) of
        {ok, {FD2, Inode3, Size}} ->
          %% file was removed
          {ok, {FD2, Inode3, Size}};
        Error ->
          Error
      end
  end.

rotate_logfile(Name, _Count) ->
  case file:read_link(Name) of
    {ok, LinkedName} ->
      case filelib:file_size(LinkedName) of
        0 ->
          %% if the files size is zero, it is removed
          catch file:delete(LinkedName);
        _ ->
          void
      end;
    _ ->
      void
  end,
  {ok, {FD, _, _}} = create_logfile(Name, []),
  file:close(FD).

%% @doc Create name of a new file
%% @private
filename(BaseFileName, DateHour, Branch) ->
  FileName = lists:append([BaseFileName,
    suffix(DateHour, false), ".", integer_to_list(Branch)
  ]),
  case filelib:is_file(FileName) of
    true ->
      filename(BaseFileName, DateHour, Branch + 1);
    _ ->
      FileName
  end.

%% @doc Zero-padding number
%% @private
zeropad(Num, MinLength) ->
  NumStr = integer_to_list(Num),
  zeropad_str(NumStr, MinLength - length(NumStr)).
zeropad_str(NumStr, Zeros) when Zeros > 0 ->
  zeropad_str([$0 | NumStr], Zeros - 1);
zeropad_str(NumStr, _) ->
  NumStr.

%% @doc Create a suffix
%% WithHour: true/false, add Hour to filename or not
%% @private
suffix({Y, M, D, H}, WithHour) ->
  YS = zeropad(Y, 4),
  MS = zeropad(M, 2),
  DS = zeropad(D, 2),
  HS = zeropad(H, 2),
  case WithHour of
    true ->
      lists:flatten([$., YS, MS, DS, $., HS]);
    _ ->
      lists:flatten([$., YS, MS, DS])
  end.
```

then add lager_rotator to lager_file_backend in sys.config

```
{rotator, lager_rotator}
```

now I can get the log filename with date

```
debug.log (symbolic link to debug.log.20190426.2)
debug.log.20190426.1
debug.log.20190426.2
```